# What command to use instead of urllib.request.urlretrieve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I'm currently writing a script that downloads a file from a URL

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(my_url, 'my_filename')
```

The docs [`urllib.request.urlretrieve`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) state:

> The following functions and classes are ported from the Python 2 module urllib (as opposed to urllib2). They might become deprecated at some point in the future.

Therefore I would like to avoid it so I don't have to rewrite this code in the near future.

I'm unable to find another interface like `download(url, filename)` in standard libraries.  If `urlretrieve` is considered a legacy interface in Python 3, what is the replacement?

Comment: 11 years later and it is still there.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*Deprecated* is one thing, *might become deprecated at some point in the future* is another. If it suits your needs, I'd continuing using `urlretrieve`.

That said, you can use [`shutil.copyfileobj`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from shutil import copyfileobj

with urlopen(my_url) as in_stream, open('my_filename', 'wb') as out_file:
    copyfileobj(in_stream, out_file)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had no idea the shutil library even existed :)

Comment: Wow, this worked beautifully. I was looking for the same thing, but for small pieces of audio, and couldn't figure out how to save it to a file. Didn't find `urlretrieve` for a while, and I didn't realize that `urlopen` would give me the bytes -- I thought I should look for a method that can save the file, not go into the file and read/save the bits. I guess this is standard practice with programming so it should make sense, but I've never worked with I/O before. Thank you, it's way simpler than I feared it might be.

Comment: Thanks for copyfileobj! The problem with `urlretrieve` is that it has no way to determine server failure (502/404/whatever).

Comment: I'm using the **reporthook** in `urlretrieve(..)` to update a progressbar, but that argument doesn't exist in `urlopen(..)`. How can I regularly update my progressbar if I switch to `urlopen(..)`?

Comment: @y0prst: "no way" is wrong. If the server fails, you get an exception: the exact same exception (HTTPError) you would get if you'd used `urlopen()` directly -- no surprise here: [`urlretrieve()` is a just convenience wrapper around `urlopen()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/23c5f93b83f78f295313e137011edb18b24c37c2/Lib/urllib/request.py#L221-L282): if it works for you, there is no need to reimplement it yourself.

Answer (score 27):

requests is really nice for this.  There are a few dependencies though to install it.  Here is an example.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('imgurl')
with open('pic.jpg','wb') as f:
  f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Doesn't this store the response in memory though? Is there a requests alternative to urlretrieve that streams to disk?

Comment: @KyleBarron: Yes, it seems so. I suppose to properly emulate `urlretrireve` using `requests` library, one would need to use streaming as shown [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content).

Answer (score 3):

Another solution without the use of [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) and no other external libraries like [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).

```
import urllib.request

image_url = "https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(image_url)
image = response.read()

with open("image.png", "wb") as file:
    file.write(image)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Code-only answers generally considered as less useful. Please edit your answer to add some context and explain your solution.

Comment: Looks perfect to me: any negative comment?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, or if there's a "better" way, but this is what I added to the top of my script after the libraries, to make my script compatible with Python 2/3.

```
# Python version compatibility
if version.major == 3:
    from urllib.error import HTTPError
    from urllib.request import urlopen, urlretrieve

elif version.major == 2:
    from urllib2 import HTTPError, urlopen

    def urlretrieve(url, data):
        url_data = urlopen(url)
        with open(data, "wb") as local_file:
            local_file.write(url_data.read())
else:
    raise ValueError('No valid Python interpreter found.')
```

It at least seems like a handy trick, and I hope this might help someone.

Best!