# How do I download a file served behind an html page using python?

Tags: python, file, download

I' m trying to download a file from the internet using python.
I' ve tryed this code:

```
import urllib.requests
URL = 'http://www.mediafire.com/download/raju14e8aq6azbo/Getting+Started+with+MediaFire.pdf'
filename = "file.pdf"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL,filename)
```

and:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from shutil import copyfileobj

URL = 'http://www.mediafire.com/download/raju14e8aq6azbo/Getting+Started+with+MediaFire.pdf'
filename = "file.pdf"
with urlopen(URL) as in_stream, open(filename, 'wb') as out_file:
    copyfileobj(in_stream, out_file)
```

(I found this last code at: [What command to use instead of urllib.request.urlretrieve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035123/what-command-to-use-instead-of-urllib-request-urlretrieve))

The problem is that this code downloads an html document and not the .pdf file named "Getting Started with MediaFire.pdf" that I need!
I' m looking for a way to download the file that is served behind the html page.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: [this](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/06/07/python-101-how-to-download-a-file/) can be helpful

Comment: It's a bit weird that your url ends with .pdf and that you use a filename also with file.pdf

Comment: Please define damaged! It is empty? Does it contain some other information? It might be a good idea to look at the content with a hex or text editor to see it there might be an HTML error page inside.

Comment: That's because the file is not a pdf file. It's a html document. You can open with chrome/firefox/other browsers. You need to find the correct link to download. Try using "save as" in the browser - if that works, then the python code will work

Comment: I answer to AJK : I tryed with the correct URL : http://www.mediafire.com/download/raju14e8aq6azbo/Getting+Started+with+MediaFire.pdf , but the problem is the same !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because the link you're trying to download is not a pdf file. It's a html document. You can open with chrome/firefox/other browsers.

You need to find the correct link to download. Try using "save as" in the browser - if that works, then the python code will work

Just because a URL ends with ".pdf" doesn't imply it is really a pdf.
For your example the correct link is - http://download834.mediafire.com/dsq8ih5dubng/raju14e8aq6azbo/Getting+Started+with+MediaFire.pdf which actually downloads the file if you use ctrl+s or wget or curl.

Comment: I tryed with the correct URL : http://www.mediafire.com/download/raju14e8aq6azbo/Getting+Started+with+MediaFire.pdf , but the problem is the same !

Comment: can you explain : " try using 'save as' on the browser ? "

Comment: @Vinciuz that is still not the correct URL, could you check the one I've mentioned above ? Also, by save as I meant - press ctrl+s on your keyboard or right click anywhere on the screen and choose "save as"

Comment: Also, there's no way that to find the pdf hidden behind a html page - the only way I can think of is to parse through the html doc and finding it ... but that's not full proof and that could be another link with .pdf at the end. Basically, there's no way to find the pdf behind the html page in general :(

Comment: Excuse me AJK, in the previous comment I wrote the wrong URL. I used : http://www.mediafire.com/download/raju14e8aq6azbo/Getting+Started+with+MediaFire.pdf

Comment: So.. is it impossible to download a file from the iternet by a python program  ?

Comment: That's unusual. I just tried your second code again using the URL i provided and python 3.4.2 and it does work correctly - I am able to open the file using evince (my pdf reader in ubuntu) also. Could you tell me which OS you use and why python version ?

Comment: AJK, I found the way !

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, sometimes I am the most ninny person in the world !
JDK was right, I used the wrong URL all the times, even when JDK sayed me to change the URL, I changed it using another wrong URL !

SO

I marked JDK's answer like the correct one AND down below I posted the code that i finally used :

```
import urllib2,fpformat

url = "http://download1063.mediafire.com/qjhujh1ajzwg/raju14e8aq6azbo/Getting+Started+with+MediaFire.pdf"

file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
f = open(file_name, 'wb')
meta = u.info()
file_size = int(meta.getheaders("Content-Length")[0])
print "Downloading: %s Bytes: %s" % (file_name, file_size)
print ""

file_size_dl = 0
block_sz = int(fpformat.fix(file_size/110,0))
print block_sz

while True:
    buffer = u.read(block_sz)
    if not buffer:
        break
    file_size_dl += len(buffer)
    f.write(buffer)
    status = ( file_size_dl * 100 ) /  file_size
    print status , ' %  - ',file_size_dl,' byte su ',file_size,' byte'
f.close()
print " complete ! "
```

It isn' t the most useful code, I' m working on a code that is more fast and correct and I will post it down below as soon as I finish it !