# Python WebScraper - object has no attribute 'urlretrieve'

Tags: python, html, image, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to create a python webscraper that downloads a certain amount of images from a url, to my current directory. However for the following code:

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(each, filename)
```

It is saying that: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'urlretrieve' when running the program

Here is the full code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


url = 'https://unsplash.com/s/photos/download'

 

def download_imgs(url, amountOfImgs):
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    #parsing the html from the url
    page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")
    images = [img for img in page_soup.findAll('img')]
    counter = 0
    #compiling the unicode list of image links
    image_links = [each.get('src') for each in images]

    for each in image_links:
        if(counter <= amountOfImgs):
            filename = each.split('/')[-1]
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(each, filename)
            counter += 1
        else:
            return image_links




print(download_imgs(url, 5))
```

Comment: Can you share the traceback?

Comment: have you seen this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035123/what-command-to-use-instead-of-urllib-request-urlretrieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when you imported just URLOpen, you missed everything else.

I did it a bit differently, I got the html using the requests.get method, and removed the need for url open, you could just do 
import urlopen, urlretrieve

if you want to use mine, I know it worked,

```html
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import requests

url = 'https://unsplash.com/s/photos/download'



def download_imgs(url, amountOfImgs):
    req=requests.get(url)
    html=req.text
    #parsing the html from the url
    page_soup = soup(html, "html.parser")
    images = [img for img in page_soup.findAll('img')]
    counter = 0
    #compiling the unicode list of image links
    image_links = [each.get('src') for each in images]

    for each in image_links:
        if(counter <= amountOfImgs):
            filename = each.split('/')[-1]
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(each, filename)
            counter += 1
        else:
            return image_links




print(download_imgs(url, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks this helped alot! The only problem I have now is that when I ran the program I got files with weird names like: “photo-1550028061-1de667deea35?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80”.

Comment: I also have an error when trying to open it, I think I must've parsed the html text wrong in my web scrapper

Comment: Yeah, grabbing the name based off the url is going to be a bit of a weird process like this because of the fact that they might be passing parameters via the URL and they get appended. 

I went to the url, and then if you right click an image on the page, and hit "Copy Image Path" you will get the url, example;

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1550028061-1de667deea35?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1268&q=80

So its gonna turn out like that all weird with that many chars.