# file retrieving from url python

Tags: python, urllib, urlretrieve

I keep getting the error message about syntax error. The file is easily downloadable if I use the url in the browser, but I cannot manage to get the data for learning through jupyter by writing the code.
Would be good if somebody could help me to solve this issue.
Thank you.

```
import urllib.request
url = "https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~./enron/enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz"`
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,
   filename="C:\Users\SnajderovaM\Documents\Training\Udacitynanodegree\Machinelearning\emails\enron_mail_20150507.tar.gz")
```

Comment: what is 'the error message about syntax error'?

Answer (score 0):

[urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) is a function defined in the library itself and not under `requests`

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(url, filename)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035123/what-command-to-use-instead-of-urllib-request-urlretrieve