# Possible to download file content without creating temporary on-disk file?

Tags: python-3.x

Downloading a file with `urllib.request.urlretrieve`creates a temporary file. While this can be deleted with `urllib.request.urlcleanup()`, I'd like to know whether there is a way to download a file's content directly to a byte array without that process generating any on-disk temporary files?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15035123/what-command-to-use-instead-of-urllib-request-urlretrieve

Comment: @StSav012 that question/answers is not about the temporary on-disk file

Comment: Actually, it is. There are [answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15035210/8554611) and [answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48483216/8554611) that provide a code to read the response into memory, without creating a file.

Comment: @StSav012 are you sure these commands do not create any temporary files behind the curtain?

Comment: Unless the OS lacks RAM and caches its content, there is no utilization of disk when the commands performed. You can always check [the source](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/requests/sessions/#Session.get) to be 100% certain.

Comment: @StSav012 thanks, if you make that an answer I can accept it